# Is it possible to aggregate such different cases in a single query?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in MongoDB with many documents like the ones below:

```
    [{
    action: "SEND_ACTION_START",
    data: {
        stuff: {
            delivered: {
                a: 1,
                b: 2,
                c: 3
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    action: "SEND_ACTION",
    data: {
        stuff: {
            delivered: [
                {0: {
                    a: 1,
                    b: 2,
                    c: 3
                }}
            ]
        }
    }   
},
{
    action: "SEND",
    data: {
        stuff: {
            delivered: [
                {0: {
                    a: 1,
                    b: 2,
                    c: 3
                }},
                {1: {
                    a: 11,
                    b: 22,
                    c: 33
                }}
            ],
            marker: 0
        }
    }
}]
```

Every case in the above array of documents has its own different structure: the first one is easy to query for fields, but having the other two makes the task difficult.
The second document contains an array of *delivered* with only a single element but the third case can contain many objects inside the array and that's the reason of the *marker* field which indicates which element on the array should be pulled out.
I would like to retrieve such documents in a single aggregation query (which will reduce the database stress as it is in a production environment), and get something like the document below:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
```

Can it be made in MongoDB from 4.4 version on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/kZSugkMmogf

Guess, the keys 0 and 1 are redundant.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      action: "SEND",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$data.stuff.delivered",
          {
            $toInt: "$data.stuff.marker"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": 3
    }
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/6utBamY5-KW

I'm sure it can be simplified:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data.stuff"
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      a: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                {
                  $type: "$delivered"
                },
                "object"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        //
        //
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$delivered"
          }
        },
        
      ],
      ///
      b: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                {
                  $type: "$delivered"
                },
                "array"
              ]
            }
          },
          
        },
        //
        {
          $match: {
            marker: {
              "$exists": false
            }
          }
        },
        //
        {
          $project: {
            delivered: {
              $first: "$delivered"
            }
          }
        },
        //
        {
          $project: {
            delivered: {
              $objectToArray: "$delivered"
            }
          }
        },
        //
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              $first: "$delivered.v"
            }
          }
        },
        
      ],
      //
      c: [
        {
          $match: {
            marker: {
              "$exists": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              $last: {
                $objectToArray: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$delivered",
                    {
                      $toInt: "$marker"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        //
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$v"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  //
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$a",
          "$b",
          "$c"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

```
[
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "a": 41,
        "b": 42,
        "c": 43
      },
      {
        "a": 31,
        "b": 32,
        "c": 33
      },
      {
        "a": 11,
        "b": 22,
        "c": 33
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Great! That'll do for the third case but... is there a way to get the same document for the other cases in the same query?

Comment: tbh didn't check whether it works in 4.4. This is a task for you ;)

Comment: Perfect! That's one heck of a query, :) Thanks a lot!